# Is there a callback in Volley to notify of completed network call like onPostExecute in Async Task?

Tags: java, android, android-volley

Is there any call backs on Volley to know when a network call is completed and completed successfully?

Thank you

EDIT: Sorry i totally forgot a vital piece of info! This is for ImageLoader and not standard Request?

Comment: Each request has a listener (passed in constructor AFAIK) which does exactly what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes,when you add a request to be sent,you can set a callback for it,and it will be invoked when the request has finished or failed,like this:

```
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest("http://www.baidu.com",
    new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.d("TAG", response);
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.e("TAG", error.getMessage(), error);
        }
    });
```

`onResponse` is used to tell you the request have finished,and `onErrorResponse` is used to tell you the request failed because some reasons like network is unreachable.

Comment: Sorry i forgot to mention this is for ImageLoader?